# How to convert my python code to run on GPU instead of CPU?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, opencv, matplotlib

I was given a python code that takes in two images as input and uses the Gabor Filter to find the correlation of RGB of the two images and saves it in a csv file.  So I need to execute the program using GPU as it takes much time and CPU utilization. I have a GeForce GTX 1050 Ti and am a complete beginner in programming.

I did some research and learned about CUDA and Tensorflow, but I am really unsure on how to go on about implementing it, and what is the best way to do it without changing much of the code.

```
#Gabor Filter
def build_filters():
    filters = []
    #tesing phrase filter - reduce
    for ksize in range(9, 19, 5):
        for theta in np.arange(45, 225, 45):
            for sigma in range(2,6,2):
                kern = cv2.getGaborKernel((ksize, ksize), sigma, theta, 5.0, 0.5, 0, ktype=cv2.CV_32F)
                kern /= 1.5*kern.sum()
                filters.append(kern)
    return filters

#Apply filter into the image
def process(images, f):
    accum = np.zeros_like(images)
    for kern in f:
        fimg = cv2.filter2D(images, cv2.CV_8UC3, kern)
        np.maximum(accum, fimg, accum)
    return accum
```

The full code: 
https://gitlab.com/t.tansuwan/image_diff_kce/blob/master/allPixelNoCrop.py

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this blog https://weeraman.com/put-that-gpu-to-good-use-with-python-e5a437168c01

Comment: I looked at it but I am really unsure on how to modify the function for parallelism with CUDA.

Comment: did you have a look at cupy?

Answer (score 1):

[Numba](https://numba.pydata.org) can convert a small sub-set of Python to .

You'll want to install numba and cudatoolkit with the conda package manager: `conda install numba cudatoolkit`. Then you can add `@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)`

I'm not sure Numba can be used with OpenCV, but you could certainly try. Python is not really suited for high-performance computation, you're better off learning FORTRAN, a shader language, or C and implementing your computation in that.